# Forward ipv6 port on github codespace

Tags: port, ipv6, portforwarding, codespaces, github-codespaces

I'm trying to create a port forwarding in github codespaces. When I run the application using an ipv4 port, the codespace itself creates port forwarding and it just works, but when I try to forward an ipv6 port, I can't access the application that runs on it.
I believe this is causing the problem because it is the only difference between the process when I list them using the command `lsof -i :8080`.

```
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node     2692 codespace   34u  IPv6 100328      0t0  TCP localhost:8080 (LISTEN)
```

```
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    10662 codespace   28u  IPv4 221351      0t0  TCP localhost:8080 (LISTEN)
```

How can I foward an ipv6 port?